# What is the best data structure to implement HashTable with one key and multiple values of different types in Python?

Tags: python

What is the best suitable data structure to implement the following scenario : 
I have one one key and corresponding to key there are some attributes.
Example : For key k101 there are 2 attributes :  count int  and status string.

Without using class and its objects for above scenario is it possible to do it HashTable or dictionary in python?

Comment: A dict *is* a hashtable, essentially, and you can have anything as value. So yes: dict.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **dict** of **tuples**:

```
d = {}
d['k101'] = (count, status)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good time to use a `namedtuple`.

```
from collections import namedtuple

nt = namedtuple('Attributes',['count','status'])

my_dict = {}
my_dict['k101'] = nt(4,'ERROR')
```

So now they are easily referenced:

```
In [79]: my_dict['k101'].count
Out[79]: 4

In [80]: my_dict['k101'].status
Out[80]: 'ERROR'
```

Comment: In above scenario how can the duct be sorted on some attribute? Say count

Comment: @user2793286 the same way you sort any other iterable, by specifying a `key` to `sorted` - i.e. `sorted(my_dict.items(),key=lambda x:x[1].count)`